# How can i move all files and folders from multiple directories?

Tags: bash

So i am writing this bash script to do all sorts of things but the last step is to move the contents of four different directories into one spot so i can run a shred command or remove or something like that (not sure what yet). this is what i have so far

```
for dir in $dir1 $dir2 $dir3 $dir4; do
     mv -vi ./* $CYCL
done
```

would this loop remove all files and folders from those directories at once? or would i have to change it?

edit: changed code . there was a function in there that i replaced with the original code

Comment: I think `mv $dir/* $CYCL`, but you do not really need a loop, `mv $dir1/* $dir2/* $dir3/* $dir4/* $CYCL` and you really should use the full path in scripts, ./* is ambiguous can will yield unpredictable results. I would trust $dir1 and $CYCL are full paths to some location.

Comment: You set variable `dir` but then not use it?

Comment: Also, if your directories or files have spaces, you will have problems. You need to quote your variables.

Comment: And if you decide that `shred` should be used, if your previous `mv` was from a separate partition, there may still be remnants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The concise way:

  ```
  mv -vi {$dir1,$dir2,$dir3,$dir4}/* $CYCL
  ```

  I don't know why you're using the `-i` option for files you want to delete anyway. You don't care if anything is overwritten, you're just adding more manual steps.
- Using your loop:

  ```
  for dir in $dir1 $dir2 $dir3 $dir4; do
     mv -vi $dir/* $CYCL
  done
  ```

The `for var in list; do ; done` syntax will sequentially assign the value of each element in the list to the variable `X` and then run whatever is in the `do` block. If you don't mention the variable you used nothing is done to it. For example, this will simply print "hello" 3 times:

```
for i in Tom Dick Harry; do echo hello; done
hello
hello
hello
```

If you want to actually do something to the elements of your list, you will need to refer to the variable you assigned them to:

```
$ for i in Tom Dick Harry; do echo hello $i; done
hello Tom
hello Dick
hello Harry
```

So, your loop was running `mv ./* $CYCL` which would have moved the contents of your **current directory** into whatever is the value of `$CYCL`. It would not have touched the contents of dirs 1-4 in any way.

Comment: ok. i thought the the loop would cycle through the directories so that the current directory would change each time. Didn't know that i had to use the variable